# 2 differeent objectt instance printing same result of first instance

Tags: python

```
from iqoptionapi.stable_api import IQ_Option

def connect_to_iq():


    API = IQ_Option('example01@gmail.com','example01')
    
    API.connect()
    
    
    API_2 = IQ_Option('example02@gmail.com','example02')
    
    API_2.connect()
    
    
    print(API.get_balance())
    
    print(API_2.get_balance())
  
connect_to_iq()
  
    # Make the same result i dont know why.
```

Account One Balance is 10036
Account Two Balance is 10000

But what is prints is:

10036
10036
I am not able to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: You should check out the official issues page before posting here; this exact issue is already something people are talking about there. [here](https://github.com/Lu-Yi-Hsun/iqoptionapi/issues/327) is a link. Essentially they're saying that you can only connect to one account per process; you'd have to use multiprocessing to connect to multiple accounts simultaneously from what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

did you try giving your function email and pass parameters ?

```
def connect_to_iq(email, password):
    API = IQ_Option(email, pass)
    API.connect()
    return API.get_balance()

connect_to_iq('example01@gmail.com','example01')
connect_to_iq('example02@gmail.com','example02')
```

Comment: I don't think that this would solve the issue as, even though it looks nicer, it's functionally equivalent to the OP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help but the result was the same:
OUTPUT :
1- 9746.68
2 -9746.68

Comment: My friend recommended me to use multiprocessing because it would "reset everything"

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the library, it holds state (ssid == session id I think) as global referenced variables. One solution I could think of is to instantiate the library per <strike>thread</strike> **process**.

That means import the library inline.

```
class ApiProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    api = None

    def __init__(self, email, password):
        super().__init__()

        # Set parameters
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

    def run(self):
        # Run
        # Import the library as it will instantiate it, but this time per thread
        from iqoptionapi.stable_api import IQ_Option
        self.api = IQ_Option(self.email, self.password)
        self.api.connect()
        print(self.api.get_balance())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process1 = ApiProcess("example01@gmail.com", "example01")
    process2 = ApiProcess("example02@gmail.com", "example02")

    process1.start()
    process2.start()
```

Do note, I didn't test this. It might not work, but from my understanding it should work.

EDIT: Changed to multiprocessing, not mutithreading as threads share memory

Comment: this is an excellent explanation, thanks for sharing it with me, but at the moment it didn't work this was the output:

1 = none

2 = 9783.4

Comment: My friend recommended me to use multiprocessing because it would "reset everything"

Comment: @Vinie I changed it to multiprocessing, your friend is right as threads do share memory

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem with Multiprocess.

```
from iqoptionapi.stable_api import IQ_Option
from multiprocessing import Process

def conectar_iq(email,senha):

    API = IQ_Option(str(email),str(senha))
    
    API.connect()
    
    print(API.get_balance())
    

if __name__ == '__main__':

    processar = Process(target=conectar_iq, args=('example01@gmail.com','example01',))
    process_two = Process(target=conectar_iq, args=('example02@gmail.com','example02',))
    processar.start()
    process_two.start()
```